# MySQL Natural Sort Does Not Work

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have scrubbed SO and Googled for hours.  I can not find a natural sort ORDER BY clause that gives the proper results.  Here is sample data and how I want the results to look.  Also, I don't want to create separate select columns for sorting.  I need the ORDER BY clause to do all the sorting.  Thank you for any and all help.

```
Values          Values (ASC)         Values (DESC)
LS1 Jul-15      LS0 NS               8
8               LS0 NS               5
LS0 NS          LS0 NS               4
4               LS0 NS               3
LS0 NS          LS0 NS               1
LS0 NS          LS0 NS              -1
LS0 NS          LS1 Jul-15          LS1 Jul-15
LS0 NS          -1                  LS0 NS
LS0 NS          1                   LS0 NS
-1              3                   LS0 NS
3               4                   LS0 NS
1               5                   LS0 NS
5               8                   LS0 NS
```

I went with the following based on Gordon's solution

```
ORDER BY (CASE when value REGEXP '^LS' then 1 else 0 end) DESC , CAST( value as decimal(20,2)) DESC
```

It works partially but the fields with text are not sorting correct.  It is coming back as:

```
LS0 NS
LS3 May-15
LS2 Jun-15
LS4 Apr-15
```

Any ideas on how to sub sort the values with text based on the above ORDER BY?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the numbers last, you can specify that:

```
order by (case when value REGEXP '^[-]?[0-9]+$' then 1 else 0 end),
         value asc
```

And for descending:

```
order by (case when value REGEXP '^[-]?[0-9]+$' then 1 else 0 end) desc,
         value desc
```

EDIT:

The numbers in your question all have one digit.  Your comment introduces another problem.  You can handle this as:

```
order by (case when value REGEXP '^[-]?[0-9]+$' then 1 else 0 end) desc,
         (value + 0) desc, value desc
```

`value + 0` converts the value to a number, based on leading digits.  If there are none, then the value is 0.

Comment: Thanks Gordon that definitely works to move the letters to top and bottom, but the numbers are out of order.  Here is a sample values returned: 'cv,cv,cv,9,8,48,39,0,-7,-48,-25'  Is there a second case we can add or something?